# showing already saved files in Kendo UI upload using MVVM declarative method

Tags: file-upload, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I have a requirement where I am using upload control of Telerik KENDO UI to upload new files and also show already saved files.

I want to do this using declarative way of MVVM

```
<input name="files" id="files" type="file" data-role="upload"
       data-multiple="true" 
       data-async='{ "saveUrl":"SaveRequestFile", 
                     "removeUrl": "RemoveRequestFile", 
                     "autoUpload": true}'
       data-bind='events:{ upload: onUpload, remove:onRemove, error:onError}' 
       required 
       data-required-msg="File is required" 
       data-files="filesUploaded" >
```

How to use data-files in above scenario?

Comment: I am trying this inside custom popup. but data-bind event onUpload gives me error : n is not a function. any idea ?